# How would you pick a uniform random element in linked list with unknown length?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

How would you pick a uniform random element in linked list with unknown length in one pass or if not two passes?

Comment: I am afraid you'll have to put a little more effort in your question and make it crystal clear what you're asking

Comment: ok. how would you pick a uniform random element in linked list with unknown length?

Comment: If that's your question, it's an interesting question. Please edit your question accordingly and I will upvote it

Comment: ok fixed post. do you have any idea how I might approach this problem? I am trying to get use this method to get the pivot element in quicksort

Comment: Two passes is trivial. On first pass, calculate the length :)

Comment: See? Bad question gets downvoted. good question gets upvoted. It's as simple as that :)

Comment: thanks. what to do on the second pass?

Comment: Is this a homework or an interview question?

Comment: @AnilBabooram: chose a random number `i` such that `0 <= i < n` and iterate the list [on the second pass] until you find the nth element - and return it.

Comment: @Amit thanks. how do I choose the random number i? Will use the rand() function?

Comment: it depends on the framework. in `c` you can use `rand() % n`, java has its own [nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) for it...

Comment: if I use a while loop to traverse the list and counting at same time. if I use ++n to count and i = rand() % n in the loop. will this generate the random number, i?

Comment: @amit ok if I use a while loop along ++length to traverse the list. If I use i= rand() % length, would "i" be the random choice at the current node?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan if I use a while loop along ++length to traverse the list. If I use i= rand() % length, would "i" be the random choice at the current node?

Answer (score 32):

Use reservoir sampling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling . You need only one pass of the data.

For picking one element:

1. Pick first element  (probability 1)
2. Later, for kth element pick it with probability 1/k (i.e. replace the existing selection with kth element)

I will let you prove that this results in uniform selection of elements.

Comment: I tried to use that but this will pick k random elements. but I will need only to select the first element

Comment: @AnilBabooram Use k=1 ? Anyways, algorithm mentioned in the post (not wiki) is for one element case.

Comment: ok if I use a while loop along ++length to traverse the list. If I use i= rand() % length, would "i" be the random choice at the current node?