# Select an element from a stream with uniform distributed probability

Tags: algorithm, random

Give you:

1. A stream (end of the stream is EOF)
2. A function `next()` to get the next element in the stream and advance the pointer in the stream
3. A random generator generating floats between 0 and 1 (inclusively) uniformly

Output:

- An element that is proven to be randomly (uniformly distributed) chosen

You can one or two variables.

You are not allowed to use array / list, and you **cannot** tell the way that `trying to get all elements out and store them all and then pick`.

---

This is an interview question.

My thinking is:

1. I use a var `cur` to store most recent kept element
2. So, if i get a new element, I generate a random 0 or 1 using generator, if it is 0 then `cur = new element`; otherwise, continue;
3. If I get EOF, then return cur

---

Is my thinking correct? How to prove?

---

Here is a same question

[How would you pick a uniform random element in linked list with unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401375/how-would-you-pick-a-uniform-random-element-in-linked-list-with-unknown-length)

Comment: Draw a probability tree.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth how? you mean draw a probability tree to prove?

Comment: For the first few stages, yes, to identify the mathematical relationship.  From that you should be able to identify a proof.

Comment: Your algorithm basically returns the element that corresponds to the last time the generator returned 0, which corresponds to the geometric distribution of the number of consecutive 1's at the end (when seen from EOF in direction beginning of the stream). That is not an uniform distribution.

Comment: You say the generator yields floats that are either 0 or 1 uniformly.  Are you sure that wasn't supposed to be floats that are **between** 0 and 1 uniformly?

Comment: Is the uniformity of the output supposed to be over the set of possible values for the outcomes, or is it that the first value, last value, or any value in between should all have equal likelihood of being the one picked?  I don't see how to do the former without keeping track of all the values that have been observed.  In the latter case, you don't care what the values are, the uniformity is over the set of indices if you **were** allowed to use an array.

Comment: @pjs Have you read amit's answer?

Comment: @NiklasB. yes, but I think the question itself is very ambiguous. I agree with Hristo Iliev's observation that if the RNG returns only zero or one, specifying that the result is a float seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let the current element's index be `i`.

Choose to 'remember' the current element at probability `1/i`. When EOF is reached, produced the element you remember.

At the end, for each element with index `i` there is a probability to be chosen:

[image]

A formal prove can be done using induction, following these guidelines.

Comment: I think this has the same problem as my answer: How to decide whether to take the element (with probability 1/i) if all you have is a random number generator that produces only 0 or 1? It's at least not O(1) anymore. Very cool trick though

Comment: @NiklasB. You only need O(log(i+1)) = O(log(i)) draws (average) to produce the probability 1/i, and you don't need more than one variable for it (iterator, basically).

Comment: Makes sense, this looks very good then. This also doesn't make any assumptions about floating point precision :)

Comment: could you please write `1/i * 1-1/(i+1)*1-1/(i+2) + ... + 1/n` more clearly? is it minus between them all like `(1/i)*1 - (1/(i+1))*1 - (1/(i+2)) - ... - (1/n)`? or just first two are minus?

Comment: is it `(1-(1/(i+1))*(1-1/(i+2))`

Comment: @JacksonTale Look at editted answer, was from android when writing the comment.

Comment: I am trying to understand it without using induction. For index i, do we need to consider the cases before i?

Comment: @JacksonTale The probability to select the i'th element is by default 1/i, this is how we defined it - regardless of the previous elements. Now, for each j>i, the probability that we won't rewrite this value is `1-1/j`. So, the probability for choosing i, and then not rewriting it is `1/i*(1-(1/(i+1)))*...*(1-(1/n))`

Comment: Is it possible to adapt this for selecting fixed numbers of records with equal probability from the stream? i.e. select 2 or 3 or ... instead of 1?

Comment: @Asad Yes, this is called [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). The idea is to hold an array of size `k` (where `k` is the number of elements you chose), with probability `k/i` (where `i` is the index you are iterating now) you replace one of the elements in this array, and if you draw to replace an element, you do it with probability `1/k` for each element.

Answer (score 5):

This algorithm chooses the last element in the stream with a probability of 1/2, so unless the stream has size = 2, this is not a valid solution.

A valid way would be to assign a random float value drawn from a uniform distribution between [0..1] to every element and return the one with the largest (or smallest) value at the end. This can be done in O(1) auxiliary space, you just need to remember the largest value and the associated element.

Comment: I was thinking of the same solution, but this sentence reads as if the generator only returns 0 or 1: _"A random generator generating floats either 0 or 1 uniformly"_. It doesn't say "floats between 0 and 1". But then, why floats?

Comment: I found this interview question online, maybe the description was wrong.

Comment: @JacksonTale Imagine the sequence of random values drawn after you have processed all elements. They are all distinct. Assign them integers according to the rank the values have in the set of all values. The resulting sequence is a uniformly drawn random permutation (because all permutations are possible and none is more likely than any other). The position of the maximum in a random permutation is uniformly distributed. Not sure about a rigorous proof though

Comment: If no random generator is given, is it possible to achieve?

Comment: @Jackson you mean if you just have a bit generator? amit proposed a solution that only requires random integers, which you can implement using random bits

Comment: @JacksonTale Then you can't make a random decision. Isn't that obvious? I mean you can implement your PRNG, if that's what you're asking

Comment: @NiklasB. `Imagine the sequence of random values drawn after you have processed all elements. They are all distinct.` Why are they all distinct? What if I get .5 and .5 twice? Similarly, does this work with a bounded data type, e.g. if a double is limited to 64-bit, then what if two numbers receive the same maximum/minimum? Is there a fair way to distinguish between the two?

Comment: @ChaimKut Well let's say the probability that two are equal is zero. It's not quite the same thing as "can't happen", in particular with real-world RNGs. But as long as you don't exceed the period of the generator, I guess you should be fine (as in, the probability of this happening is low enough to not influence the expected outcome in a significant way). If you want a solution that does not require random floats, see amit's answer

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't quite fit all of the parameters in the question.  However, this solution is based on a real-world need and code.

```
private static final SecureRandom s_random = new SecureRandom();  // Use SecureRandom for truly random selection without a pattern

public static <V> V randomValue(Iterator<V> values)
{
   V result, item;
   int count;

   result = null;

   for (count = 1, values.hasNext(); count++)
   {
      item = values.next();

      if (count == 1)  // Always select the first element
         result = item;
      else if (s_random.nextnextInt(count) == 0)  // Replace the previous random item with a new item with 1/count probability
         result = item;
   }

   if (result == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No value found");

   return(result);
}
```

The above algorithm is taken from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/select-a-random-number-from-stream-with-o1-space/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my python code for this problem (also [available with tests on my github](https://github.com/jamesbaye/dailyCodingProblems/blob/master/2020-07-02_pickRandomElementInStream.ipynb)):

```
import random as rnd

def sample(iterator):
    """ Uniform sampling of an element from an stream.
    The i-th element (indexed at 1) is sampled with probability 1/i.
    This can be shown by recurrence to lead to uniform sampling. 
    Indeed, at step n we impose p(val==n)=1/n, and all elements i before n 
    were sampled with equal probability, which is also equal to 1/n since
    p(val<n) = (n-1)*p(val==i) = 1-1/n = (n-1)/n => p(val==i) = 1/n """
    i = 1
    out = None
    for elm in iterator:
        if rnd.uniform(0,1) <= 1/i:
            out = elm
        i += 1
    return out
```